# Tag merge / synonym requests: [prototype] -> [prototyping], [type-system] -> [type-systems]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge the following tags and make them synonyms:

1. [prototype](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prototype) (14 questions) into [prototyping](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prototyping) (25)
2. [type-system](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-system) (18 questions) into [type-systems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-systems) (6)

Comment: I went through the questions and they are all about the same thing, I'll let this open for the day to see if anyone objects and then I'll merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done as requested.

- ['prototyping' tag synonyms](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/prototyping/synonyms) page:

  > The following tags will be remapped to [prototyping](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prototyping)
  >   [prototype](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prototype)
- ['type-systems' tag synonyms](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/type-systems/synonyms) page:

  > The following tags will be remapped to [type-systems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-systems)
  >   [type-system](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-system)

Comment: [status-completed] not enough for you? ;P

Comment: @YannisRizos I want something with "accepted" checkmark - to get me these precious +2 rep... oh wait there's no rep at meta :)